# Unable to display incremented value in a List in C#

Tags: c#

I am having a LIST. I am retrieving 1 record each time.

[image: Image Description]

**Code**

```
List<ClientImpressionProductSelectionM> ClientImpressionProdSelection = _customerPrintService.GetClientImpressionProductSelection().ToList();
int index = 1;
GetClientImpressionProductSel.Clear();               
generateSeqNumber();

foreach (var ProdSelection in ClientImpressionProdSelection)
{
    for (index = 1; index <= InputProduct.NdPlettes;)
    {                      
            ProdSelection.Sequence = Convert.ToInt32(GenResult);
            ProdSelection.Number = index;
            ProdSelection.ClientDestinataire = InputProduct.ClientDestinataire;
            ProdSelection.LieuDeLivraison = InputProduct.LieuDeLivraison;
            ProdSelection.CodeProduitClient = InputProduct.CodeProduitClient;
            ProdSelection.CodeCouleurClient = InputProduct.CodeCouleurClient;
            ProdSelection.CodeFournisseurEMPourClient = InputProduct.CodeFournisseurEMPourClient;
            ProdSelection.AQP = InputProduct.AQP;
            ProdSelection.Produit = InputProduct.Produit;
            ProdSelection.RefFournisseur = InputProduct.RefFournisseur;
            ProdSelection.NdShipment = InputProduct.NdShipment.Value;
            ProdSelection.NdLot = InputProduct.NdLot;
            ProdSelection.Cdate = InputProduct.Cdate;
            ProdSelection.PoidsNet = InputProduct.PoidsNet;
            ProdSelection.PoidsBrut = InputProduct.PoidsBrut;
            ProdSelection.NbrPallet = InputProduct.NdPlettes.Value;
            ProdSelection.Material = InputProduct.Material;
            ProdSelection.CodClient = InputProduct.CodClient;
            ProdSelection.CodPackaging = InputProduct.CodPackaging;
            ProdSelection.CoefNetBrut = InputProduct.CoefNetBrut;
            index++;
            GetClientImpressionProductSel.Add(ProdSelection);
    }

    CalculateGrossWeight(ProdSelection); 
}
```

**Problem :**

I am able to generate N times the records but when I am trying to print a NUMBer , I am always getting last value. Please see the Image attached in the question. The second column is NUM and I am getting 4,4,4,4 instead of 1,2,3,4.

Expected result should be :

```
Seq                    NUM
180001021               1
180001021               2
180001021               3
180001021               4
```

Can anyone please help me out?

I have a list. I will always get only 1 record in a list. But if user enter InputProduct.NdPlettes value = N(Number of times) it will get repeated and display.

Comment: Omg this post was a mess, please take time to edit your question correctly in the future, it makes all the difference.

Answer (score 2):

I am going have a major guess, your problem is not in the code you supplied, its in the `GetClientImpressionProductSelection` call.

When you call `GetClientImpressionProductSelection` it is giving you the same `ClientImpressionProductSelectionM` in a list.

You are **not** creating a new `ClientImpressionProductSelectionM` for each element in your list.

When you are updating the each element,

```
foreach (var ProdSelection in ClientImpressionProdSelection)
```

you are just updating the only instantiated object. Hence you are receiving the last result

Comment: Yes , your understanding is correct. where i can add my creation code inside loop?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
List<ClientImpressionProductSelectionM> ClientImpressionProdSelection = _customerPrintService.GetClientImpressionProductSelection().ToList();
int index = 1;
GetClientImpressionProductSel.Clear();               
generateSeqNumber();

foreach (var ProdSelection in ClientImpressionProdSelection)
{
    for (index = 1; index <= InputProduct.NdPlettes;)
    {          
            ClientImpressionProductSelectionM prd = new ClientImpressionProductSelectionM();           
            prd.Sequence = Convert.ToInt32(GenResult);
            prd.Number = index;
            prd.ClientDestinataire = InputProduct.ClientDestinataire;
            prd.LieuDeLivraison = InputProduct.LieuDeLivraison;
            prd.CodeProduitClient = InputProduct.CodeProduitClient;
            prd.CodeCouleurClient = InputProduct.CodeCouleurClient;
            prd.CodeFournisseurEMPourClient = InputProduct.CodeFournisseurEMPourClient;
            prd.AQP = InputProduct.AQP;
            prd.Produit = InputProduct.Produit;
            prd.RefFournisseur = InputProduct.RefFournisseur;
            prd.NdShipment = InputProduct.NdShipment.Value;
            prd.NdLot = InputProduct.NdLot;
            prd.Cdate = InputProduct.Cdate;
            prd.PoidsNet = InputProduct.PoidsNet;
            prd.PoidsBrut = InputProduct.PoidsBrut;
            prd.NbrPallet = InputProduct.NdPlettes.Value;
            prd.Material = InputProduct.Material;
            prd.CodClient = InputProduct.CodClient;
            prd.CodPackaging = InputProduct.CodPackaging;
            prd.CoefNetBrut = InputProduct.CoefNetBrut;
            index++;
            GetClientImpressionProductSel.Add(prd);
    }

    CalculateGrossWeight(ProdSelection); 
}
```

You need to create a **new** instance of the object that you want to add to your list, otherwise it will add a reference to the same object and that is why you get the same values.